# Float menu items, if they are over screen

Tags: css

If the menu has more than 7 menu items and the resolution is 1600 x 900 px then e. g. the 8th menu entry is no longer completely displayed.

[Demo-Page](https://wp-style-demo.fs-bezirk.de)

How can I float the menu items in the second line, if the resolution is not enough for the items?

Comment: why you are not using bootstrap for create responsive web page?

Comment: it is using bootstrap

<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='https://wp-style-demo.fs-bezirk.de/wp-content/themes/foodsharing-bezirks-website/inc/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=5.2.2' type='text/css' media='all' />

Comment: ok so use bootstrap navbar like this https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Cav6w/

Comment: there is a hamburger menu for smaller than 1200 px available.

Comment: you can handle it with css @media

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul.menu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;/*Remove if need multiple lines*/
  white-space: nowrap;/*Remove if need multiple lines*/
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home">FAIR-TEILER</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm using this nav class -> https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker
is a better nav class available or how can I change ul to div?

Comment: Don't change that, I edited the answer. You can achieve this with plain css as shown in the answer snippet

Comment: Thanks, but I have no success.

Comment: tried removing `overflow: auto;` and `white-space:nowrap;` for second line?

Comment: Added - `.navbar-expand-xl .navbar-collapse {
    
    overflow: hidden; /*Added*/
}` and `#main-nav ul {
     overflow: auto;/*Added*/
    white-space: nowrap;/*Added*/
}`

Comment: Thanks, but I have further no success. You can look at https://gitlab.com/foodsharing-dev/ag-bezirkswebsite/foodsharing-wordpress-bezirks-website and https://wp-style-demo.fs-bezirk.de/

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add **nav** class in ul

```
<ul id="menu-hauptmenue" class="nav navbar-nav">
```

Comment: this put each menu item in seperate line.

Comment: I gave this solution because the 8th menu was not visible on 1600 resolution but now it is visible. What's the main issue now that you are facing? If you want these menus in single line before 1200 resolution then you can adjust this by decreasing font-size of menus in media query.